# How filled image background color transparent or White in codeigniter when image cropping

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way to fill up the background with white color or transparent when we crop an image in CodeIgniter? I have tried many options but nothing works. It always shows black background.

If it is possible, please suggest a solution, in which I don't need to edit the CodeIgniter core library.

Comment: which version of CI u are using?

Comment: please use this config in your croping code. 'overwrite'       => true,
It also might possible the image viewer you are using that showing black in background. Please use browser to see your cropped image. This might help

Comment: CI 3.0 @ RanaGhosh

Answer (score 0):

you have to let your first css description is null
like this:

```
body
{
    //will not execute
}
.background
{
   background-color:red;
}
```